# How can I add a bullet before a label in Xamarin foms if I am using MVVM?

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I need to add a bullet in a label, but I am using Binding for my label text. Here is what I have done but the binding doesn't work:

```
 <Label Text="&#x2022; {Binding NoticeTitle}"  FontAttributes="Bold" 
 FontSize="12"  VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" 
 HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using **StringFormat**

```
<Label Text="{Binding NoticeTitle,
                  StringFormat='&#x2022; {0}'}" />
```